# cannot install goldendict because of package dependencies

Tags: installation, package-management, dependencies

I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.10. Software Center fails to install Goldendict because of some package dependencies.

The error message looks like this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

goldendict: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be installed
            Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libphonon4 (>= 4:4.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but 2.2.1-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libvorbisfile3 (>= 1.1.2) but 1.3.2-1.3 is to be installed
            Depends: phonon but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13 is to be installed
```

the output for `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```

the output for `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

`arsen@arsen-VGN-NS325J:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse universe`

Any suggestions would be more than appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try adding the name of the packages "not to be installed" in your `apt-get install` command.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are on Ubuntu 12.04, which has most of the `libqt4` stuff preinstalled. Can you add the outputs of `lsb_release -a` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to the question.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks for noticing it, I'm using 12.10. I've added the outputs of lsb_release -a and cat /etc/apt/sources.list to the question

Comment: Can you post the complete output of the second command. There should be more the just one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I enabled the system to receive "Important security updates" and "Recommended updates" (from Software Sources, the tab "Updates")